# In angular unit test which service we should call?

Tags: angular, jasmine

Hi I am writing unit test cases in jasmine. I am interacting with restful API's in my components. I am writing unit cases for delete,add user etc. I have services which will call API's and I have written some mock services which will not interact with API's. I have created JSON data son all API's will grab data from this JSON object. Now I have written unit test for delete user. Now I should call my real services those interact with server or mock services I created which will interact with local JOSN data? Below is my sample mock service and unit test.

Below is unit test for delete user.

```
it('should delete the user', async(() => {
    spyOn(service, 'deleteUserEndpoint');
    let button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#delete');
    button.click();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(service.deleteUserEndpoint('101')).toHaveBeenCalled();
    })
}));
```

Below is my mock service.

```
deleteUserEndpoint(userid: string) {
    var deleteUserUserOnboard = { result: true };
    return Observable.of(deleteUserUserOnboard);
}
```

Can someone confirm me which services I should call? Also When i run above code I am getting below error.

```
Failed: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for deleteUserEndpoint()
```

Can someone help me to make my unit test runs  successfully? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First , You should *never* call a real REST API service or anything that interact with the external world in a unit test, this is the work of an integration test. The reason for that is that your tests must be able to assess whether the code is running smoothly when your external dependencies succeed but also fail ... and this is why mock are useful

To mock your service, use `fixture.debugElement.injector.get()` :

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [Component], 
        imports: [...]
    }).overrideComponent(Component, {
        set: {
            providers: [Service]

            OR 

            providers : [{
                provide : Service, useClass : ServiceMock
            }]


        }
    }).compileComponents();
}));

beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(Component);
    target.detectChanges();
});


it('should delete the user when service succeed', async(() => {
    let service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Service)
    spyOn(service, 'deleteUserEndpoint');
    let button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#delete');
    button.click();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        expect(service.deleteUserEndpoint).toHaveBeenCalledWith("101");
    })
}));



it('should show error message when service fails, async(() => {
    let service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Service)
    spyOn(service, 'deleteUserEndpoint').and.throwError("Deletion Failed");
    let button = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#delete');
    button.click();
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
        // test here that you have the appropriate error message displayed
    })
}));
```

Comment: Thank you safiyya. Service is my mock service right? Also which name space i should use for target/

Comment: Yes, `service` is your mocked service. Also , `target` is actualy `fixture` in your case, will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you. My mock service name is UserOnboardEndpointMock. When i do this I get error   NullInjectorError: No provider for UserOnboardEndpointMock!.

Comment: This means that your test is not setup correctly. Remember that jasmine has to be able to instantiate all providers needed in your component to run your test... I'll post a small example on how your test setup should look like in a sec

Comment: I am getting below error. Failed: Uncaught (in promise): Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got undefined.
Usage: expect(<spyObj>).toHaveBeenCalled()
Error: <toHaveBeenCalled> : Expected a spy, but got undefined.

Comment: Your syntax for checking that the spy has been called is wrong, it should be `expect(service.deleteUserEndPoint).toHaveBeenCalledWith("101")` . See updated answer

Comment: Yeah i changed and got Expected spy deleteUser to have been called with [ '101' ] but it was never called.

Comment: I dont use `whenStable` myself but aren't you supposed to call `fixture.detectChanges()` at some point in your test ? https://angular.io/guide/testing

Comment: what would be the result after clicking the delete button?

Comment: I changed to            expect(service.deleteUser).toHaveBeenCalledWith["101"]; and it worked. Is that square brackets were issue?